# How to reset Jquery remote validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am very new to Javascript and all. I am working on a registration page right now. I used a template given by my friends and I am trying to make it work with Laravel 5.3.

What I am trying to achieve here is: to validate if the email has already in the database. Now the validation works. It tells if the email exists or not. But once done that, no matter how user changes email input, it always show that the email has been taken.

```
var form = $(".form-signup");
$('#submit-form').click(function(e) {
        form.validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/check/",
                        type: "get"
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 16
                },
                password2: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 16,
                    equalTo: '#password'
                },
                terms: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: 'Enter your first name',
                    minlength: 'Enter at least 3 characters or more'
                },
                email: {
                    required: 'Enter email address',
                    email: 'Enter a valid email address',
                    remote: 'Email has been taken'
                },
                password: {
                    required: 'Write your password',
                    minlength: 'Minimum 6 characters',
                    maxlength: 'Maximum 16 characters'
                },
                password2: {
                    required: 'Write your password',
                    minlength: 'Minimum 6 characters',
                    maxlength: 'Maximum 16 characters',
                    equalTo: '2 passwords must be the same'
                },
                terms: {
                    required: 'You must agree with terms'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                console.log(element);
                if (element.is(":radio") || element.is(":checkbox")) {
                    element.closest('.option-group').after(error);
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
        }
    });
     e.preventDefault();
        if (form.valid()) {
            $(this).addClass('ladda-button');
            var l = Ladda.create(this);
            l.start();
            setTimeout(function() {
                //AJAX added.
                var formData = {
                    _token:$(this).data('token'),
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    password: $('#password').val(),
                    password_confirmation: $('#password2').val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/register',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        var token =     $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                        if (token) {
                            return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                        }
                    },
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    statusCode: {
                        200: function (data) {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        500: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            alert('not valid');
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my front end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="themes-lab" name="author" />
    <meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('admin_assets/images/favicon.png')}}">
    <link href="{{asset('admin_assets/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{asset('admin_assets/css/ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/icheck/skins/all.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/bootstrap-loading/lada.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="account separate-inputs boxed" data-page="signup">
    <!-- BEGIN LOGIN BOX -->
    <div class="container" id="login-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="account-wall">
                    <i class="user-img icons-faces-users-03"></i>
                    <form class="form-signup" role="form">
                        <div class="append-icon">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control form-white name" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
                            <i class="icon-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="append-icon">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-white email" placeholder="Email" required>
                            <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="append-icon">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-white password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
                            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="form-control form-white password2" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
                            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="terms option-group">
                            <label  for="terms" class="m-t-10">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" data-checkbox="icheckbox_square-blue" required/>
                            I agree with terms and conditions
                            </label>  
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark m-t-20" data-style="expand-left">Register</button>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <p class="pull-right m-t-20"><a href="user-login-v1.html">Already have an account? Sign In</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LOCKSCREEN BOX -->
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/gsap/main-gsap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/backstretch/backstretch.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/bootstrap-loading/lada.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/plugins/jquery-validation/additional-methods.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/js/plugins.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('admin_assets/js/pages/login-v1.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, once a user input a used email and receives error message, they won't be able to proceed and the button will keep spinning.

[Screenshot on the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em6xu.png)

Can any one suggests any possible solutions? It will be great to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yay, I finally figured out myself after plenty of researching.

The reason being, jQuery validation does NOT wait for remote response. That is why the program runs even if a email is already taken.

To solve this, just simply add

```
async: false
```

in the remote. and it will work just fine!